# how to split long command line in multiple lines with quote inside?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, batch-processing

How can i write this multiline command:

```
"my.exe"^
 -Libraries="toto;^
tutu"^
```

it's work well for the first line `"my.exe"^` but stop in the second line `-Libraries="toto;^` and thus ignore the third line `tutu"^`

Comment: As far as I know, you can _not_ split a quoted content in several lines ended in caret `^`, that is to say, each `"quoted item"` must be complete in the same _physical line_

Comment: Depending upon the executable, it may be possible to change ```"toto;^``` to ```"toto;"^```, and ```tutu"^``` to ```<space>"tutu"^```. _(Obviously the last trailing caret character is needed only if continuing to the next line.)_

Comment: @Compo: Yes, that is to say: each quoted item must have their both quotes in each line separated by caret. It is not possible to put an open quote in one line^ and the closing quote in a posterior line.

Comment: @Aacini, I,m unsure if you're telling me I'm somehow mistaken, or correcting me on something you think I said. If you are agreeing with some or part of my comment, that should be directed towards the readership, not directly to myself. If you are telling me that my comment, or some part of it, was incorrect, then please tell me which part and why.

Comment: @Compo: I just noted that you basically repeat what I said in my comment using other words. I said: _each `"quoted item"` must be complete in the same physical line_. You said: _change `"toto;^` to `"toto;"^` and `tutu"^` to `<space>"tutu"^`_, so you indicate to complete both quotes for each item in each line...

Comment: The important thing when using the method I mentioned, is that all continuation lines (beginning with a doublequote) require at least that leading space character. There are less rules with what Aacini and jeb posted, (as long as your OCD can handle the ruined editor syntax highlighting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
"my.exe"^
 -Libraries=^"toto;^
tutu"
```

The key is to have balanced quotes (multiple of 2) in each line, or escape unbalanced quotes to get a balanced line